# Android AndEngine animate backwards

Tags: android, andengine

I am using andengine and I have an animated Sprite.

I use `scene.animate(duration,0,5,1)` to animate the sprite from first tile to the last.

I am wondering if somehow I could do the animation backwards so that it starts from the last tile to the first tile.
What I need to get is `0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,0` .

Comment: check it:http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/adding-a-view-above-a-game-t498.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
sprite.animate(long[] pFrameDurations, int[] pFrames, int pLoopCount)
```

where 
Animate specifics frames

```
Parameters:
    pFrameDurations: indicates the time delays between animations and must have the same length as pFrames.
    pFrames: indices of the frames to animate. // Here you specify your 0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,0
    pLoopCount: indicates the no of times you want to repeat the animation
```